# If O2 value is updated, then I need to send email to address in C2 with a template. The email should send only to C2 if the cell O2 is updated

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using google spreadsheet.

I have Email addresses of participants in C column, and their corresponding Status in O column.( The status will be either, DONE or OPEN or ONGOING or empty).

If O2 value is updated, then I need to send email to address in C2 with a template. The email should send only to C2 if the cell O2 is updated.

I hope you can help me with this.

I tried this script but it sends to all email everytime.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks,

```
function StatusChange() {


  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("R & A").activate();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow(); 

  var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template for Email").getRange(1,1).getValue();

  var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();

  if((lr-1) > quotaLeft){
    Browser.msgBox("You have " + quotaLeft + " left and you're trying to send " + (lr-1) + " emails. Emails were not sent.");
  } else {

    for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){

      var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
      var currentSheetTitle = ss.getRange(i, 11).getValue();
      var currentName = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();

      var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}",currentName).replace("{title}",currentSheetTitle);
      var subjectLine = "Reminder: " + currentSheetTitle + " Status Change";


    MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody);


    } // close for loop


  } //close else statement


}
```

If O2 value is updated, then I need to send email to address in C2 with a template. The email should send only to C2 if the cell O2 is updated.

Comment: How is this related to the programming language C (the tag you added)? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using an `onEdit` installable trigger, you'll need to set this up by either going to your triggers or running the below code [supplied by Google](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) once.

```
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('statusChange')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}
```

By doing this you can check if column O is being updated, then run your `if else` statements based on that result. I've also cleaned up some of the variables so that you're not doing multiple `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` calls unnecessarily.

**Note: you won't be able to run the below script manually, it'll run automatically when the sheet is edited.**

```
function statusChange(e){

  var sp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sp.getSheetByName('R & A');
  var row = e.range.getRow(); //get row # for edited range
  var col = e.range.getColumn(); //get column # for edited range

  if(col === 15){ //check if column O was updated

    var templateText = sp.getSheetByName("Template for Email").getRange(1,1).getValue();

    var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();

    if(quotaLeft < 1){
      Browser.msgBox("You have " + quotaLeft + " left and you're trying to send 1 email. Email was not sent.");
    } else{

      var currentEmail = ss.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
      var currentSheetTitle = ss.getRange(row, 11).getValue();
      var currentName = ss.getRange(row, 4).getValue();

      var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}",currentName).replace("{title}",currentSheetTitle);
      var subjectLine = "Reminder: " + currentSheetTitle + " Status Change";

      MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody);
    } //close else statement
  } //close if statement
}
```

Since all you're trying to do is send an email for the row you've edited, you don't need the `for` statement you had in the script. You can get the row and column for the range that has been edited and base the rest of the script off of that instead.

Comment: Hi Ross thank you for your help, I copy and past your updated script and an error prompted. TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 5, file "Code")

Comment: Hi Ross, also if I can message you directly and call you on other app like skype so you can guide me, I am new to this apps script so it will be so much help for me if you can help. Thank you so much.

Comment: You won't be able to run the script manually, I did mention that in the answer. This script runs automatically when column O is updated once your trigger is set up correctly.

Comment: How and what should be my trigger? please help. Thanks a lot Ross.

Comment: it does not send email automatically even if the sheet is edited

Comment: Run the first script in my answer to set up the trigger for the email script.

Comment: whenever I edit any cell on column O, it does not send email. I already run the first script that you sent.

Comment: One more thing Ross, it sends the email 3 times whenever I edit the cell on column O. How will I make it just 1 email? Thanks.

Comment: I already saw the problem, I run the trigger multiple times that is why. I already deleted excess triggers. Thank you.

Comment: Great - please mark the answer as correct if this fulfilled your requirements.